# How to transform a point cloud from camera coordinates to world coordinates

Tags: kinect, laser, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a Kinect sensor at about 1.5 meters elevation angled downwards by 40 degrees and which can also pan to arbitrary positions, and I'd like to transform the camera/depth/points point cloud from camera coordinates to world coordinates (or an egocentric world frame) so that I can then produce a correct fake laser scan from a fixed horizontally aligned virtual laser scanner at the base of the robot.  How do I do this?

So far I've been trying pcl_ros::transformPointCloud, but without much success.  I don't want to actually move the points (as seen in Rviz), merely reassign their coordinates relative to a different frame.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9506/how-to-transform-a-point-cloud-from-camera-coordinates-to-world-coordinates/) by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 995 on 2011-03-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

pcl_ros::transformPointCloud is exactly what you want.  It computes the positions of each point with respect to a different coordinate frame.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-03-20**:
Ok, I think I've got it.  The variant I needed was pcl_ros::transformPointCloud(destination_frame,from_cloud,to_cloud,TransformListener)

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-03-20**:
It might be that I've been using the wrong variant.  I have been explicitly calculating a transform from one frame to another, then applying it, but that's probably not what I should be doing.